# laravel Many Records to One single record....but how?

Tags: laravel, relationship, laravel-6

I have two tables, one is `Users` and the other is `Loans`. These have one to many relationship between them. One user can have many loans and one loan belongs to one User.

Now I want to get the user from the list of loans.

```
Loan::where('user_id',  $user)->get()
```

This give me repeated array of sample user associated to the multiple loans. But I want to get only a single record, like many loans associate to one user.

Comment: Just return a single record... `Loan::where('user_id', $userId)->first();`... You're getting multiple records back since you're using `get()`, and since this is a One User to Many Loan relationship, there are going to be multiple records when you query against the `loans` table. Alternatively, why don't you just query the `users` table directly? `User::where('id', $userId)->first()`. Your approach is making it harder for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already set up relationships between User & Loan Models

```
// App\User

public function loans() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Loan');
}


// App\Loan

public function user() {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

---

Get user from the list of loans

```
$user = Loan::where('user_id', $id)->first()->user;
// eager loading version 
$loansWithUsers = Loan::with('user')->where('user_id', $id)->get();
```

Loans associate to one user

```
$loans = User::findOrFail($id)->loans;
// eager loading version 
$userWithLoans = User::with('loans')->findOrFail($id);
```

Comment: actually i have a two foreign key in loan table that are `user_id & branch_id ` both users are stored in users table and i have assign role to them.....

now  set branch_id in query and on the basis to branch_id  get (user_id) users  all information from user table .......your query give ma only one record but their is possibility where branch_id  may be same but user_id not same......Are you have any idea??

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand in your question, you want to get the user together with it's loan right ? Your query should like this.

```
$user_loans = User::with('loans')->where('id', $user_id)->get();
```

Get the user informations from loan table

```
Loan::where('user_id',  $user_id)->with('user')->get()
```

Ge the users from loans table depends on brach id

```
Loan::where('branch_id',  $branch_id)->with('user')->get();
```

Comment: actually i have a two foreign key in loan table that are user_id & branch_id both users are stored in users table and i have assign role to them..... now set branch_id in query and on the basis to branch_id get (user_id) users all information from user table .......your query give ma only one record but their is possibility where branch_id may be same but user_id not same......Are you have any idea??

Comment: you want to get user loans with an specific branch id right ?

Comment: NO, i want to get user information from loans list which contains branch_id as well as user_id.........i will compare branch_id then get information of user from the results......

Comment: i can get user information by doing this in blade file.....like `$result->user->name`

but it gives me repeated records.

Comment: you want to get loans from specific user id and brach id ?

Comment: i want to get users  from loans list specific to brantch_id